# How to kill a process that won't die?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Something went wrong with my "setroubleshootd" demon on a production server. it's taking a lot of cpu and won't die no matter what!

what i've tried

```
sudo killall -9 setroubleshootd
sudo killall -9 <<pid>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution, unfortunately, is to reboot. It's stuck in the kernel.

You can try to unjam it. But this is inherently risky. It may cause the kernel to crash. An orderly reboot is much safer.

Basically, the way you unjam it is to figure out what it's doing (using tools like `ls /proc/<pid>/fd`, `top`, and so on) and make something happen to change whatever it's stuck on. If it's stuck on a process, try killing that process. If it's stuck on a file, try removing that file. This very rarely works, but even if it does, I'd consider the system polluted and reboot it anyway.

Messing with it can cause more processes to get stuck "behind" it.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer you want, but If the process won't die, you are probably out of luck - you probably need to reboot.    (I note that the command for killing a PID is kill -9 <> rather then killall.

I suspect that there may be a very small subset of events you can get around by using the Mafic_SysRQ key if its enabled (like NFS mounts) - but I've not played with this much and it is for developers - and, I suspect, not usually enabled by default.  More info [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)